Manhwa where the female main character has divine powers and uses them to fix/maintain a magical glacier or something
I read this a couple months ago but cannot for the life of me remember the title.
I'm looking for a manhwa where the female lead (FL) has divine powers of some sort. She’s staying in a duke's(?) territory and goes out alone. She encounters a magical glacier or something that needs to be maintained with powers and she's the one that uses her powers to fix it.
I think there was another female character who also has similar abilities? And this character was maybe the one that was supposed to be fixing stuff, not the FL.
Edit: From what I recall it’s a standalone manhwa. It was in English but could have been translated from another language. It also was well drawn and coloured in a typical manhwa art style.

@Anya S - Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

@LogicDictates - I think the hair colour of the female lead was platinum blonde or white, but I’m not 100% sure.

Is this a villainess type story, where the protagonist is hated at first and everyone loves the other woman, but things change and everyone starts loving the protagonist instead? Usually a reincarnated in a book world or time rewind story.

This is I've Become a True Villainess. It is licensed by Manta.

I've died and been reincarnated as the villain of a romance novel! In order to avoid the hideous fate that awaits me, I've righted her wrongs and even gotten engaged. I should be home free, but strange things have started happening ever since the heroine appeared. Why won't her fiancé leave me alone?


The protagonist has green hair, not white or blonde, but one of the male leads (her fiance) has white hair.
The main character is the villainess of a novel; the heroine is a saintess-type character. Both of them have holy powers, not just the heroine of the original story. Both are in a territory that has a demonic glacier:

This needs to be purified to contain the demonic energy; in theory both of them can do it, but the protagonist is significantly more capable. Despite this, her fiance is appointed as the other saintess's caretaker, and lavishes her with attention while being harsh to the protagonist.

Omg yes, that’s it! Thank you :)

@AnyaS You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as accepted, which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the tour.
